# What's the correct way to write shapefile / shape file / Shapefile?

Tags: discussion

As this is a 'style' question I suspect it belongs here ... correct me if I'm wrong!

In a recent post there were suggested edits and then actual edits, changing my initial spelling of 'shapefile' to 'shape file' and finally 'Shapefile'. What's correct? Or at least generally agreed upon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the ["ESRI Shapefile Technical Description"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CI4BEBYwAQ&url=http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf&ei=9z-mT7WIDJCh-Qa6wYzqAg&usg=AFQjCNHp9v_VCrbagYu23yPhKgqEO9KX8Q):

> An ESRI **shapefile** consists of a main file, an index file, and a dBASE table.

Comment: Yep, that's what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) says too ... I'll continue writing it that way.